# Bounded sequence has Cauchy subsequence w.r.t. $ (x|y)_0:=\sum^\infty_{n=1} 2^{-n}\phi_n(x)\phi_n(y).$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, separable-spaces, reflexive-space

Let $X$ be a separable reflexive real Banach space and let $(\phi_n)$ be a dense sequence in
$$\{ \phi\in X'\,|\,\|\phi\|\leq 1 \}.$$
Consider in $X$ the scalar product $( \cdot| \cdot)_0 $ defined by
$$ (x|y)_0:=\sum^\infty_{n=1} 2^{-n}\phi_n(x)\phi_n(y).$$

Prove that:

(a) if $\|\cdot\|_0$ is the norm induced by such scalar product, then $\|x\|_0\leq \|x\|$ for all $x \in X$,

(b) every bounded sequence in $X$ admits a Cauchy subsequence with respect to the norm $\|\cdot\|_0$.

---

I did the first request while I had problems with b).

**My attempts and questions:**

a) $ \|x\|^2_0:=\sum^\infty_{n=1} 2^{-n}(\phi_n(x))^2\leq\sum^\infty_{n=1} 2^{-n}\|\phi_n\|^2\|x\|^2\leq \sum^\infty_{n=1} 2^{-n}\|x\|^2=\|x\|^2$.

b) This request gave me some problems. *My attempts:* let $x_n$ be a bounded sequence. Since $X$ is reflexive there exists weakly convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}$... my idea is to prove that this sub-sequence is Cauchy with respect to $\|\cdot\|_0$ but I do not know how to prove it. Since $x_{n_k} \rightharpoonup x$ we have in particular that $\{\phi_n(x_{n_k}) \}_k$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$ for every $n$ fixed. Could we try to use this fact? What do you think of my idea? Is this the right way to solve the exercise?
Where it is necessary to use that $X$ is separable and that $(\phi_n)$ is dense in the ball?

*I would like to have a hint for concluding point b)*.

Thanks in advance.

---

**UPDATE: my solution of point b) after the hints of @Kavi Rama Murthy.**

Let $x_n$ be a bounded sequence. Since $X$ it is reflexive there exists a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ weakly convergent to $x\in X$. I claim that it is a Cauchy subsequence. For simplicity in the notation we denote this subsequence by $x_k$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $\sum^\infty_{n=1} 2^{-n}$ is convergent there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t.
$$ \|x_k-x_j\|^2_0=\sum^\infty_{n=1} 2^{-n}(\phi_n(x_k-x_j))^2=\sum^N_{n=1} 2^{-n}(\phi_n(x_k-x_j))^2+\sum^\infty_{n=N+1} 2^{-n}(\phi_n(x_k-x_j))^2$$
$$ < \sum^N_{n=1} 2^{-n}(\phi_n(x_k-x_j))^2+\varepsilon^2/2\qquad\,\,\,\,\,\, (1)$$

By definition of weak convergence we have $\phi_n(x_k)\to\phi_n(x)$ for every $n$ fixed, in particular $\{\phi_n(x_k)\}_k$ is a Cauchy sequence for every $n$ fixed, that is there exists $k_0(n,\varepsilon)\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $$|\varphi_n(x_k-x_j)|<\dfrac{\varepsilon^2}{2\sum^N_{n=1} 2^{-n}}\qquad \forall \,i,j>k_0(n,\varepsilon)$$
Let $\overline k_0(\varepsilon):=\max\{k_0(1,\varepsilon),k_0(2,\varepsilon),...,k_0(N,\varepsilon)\}$, then for all $i,j>\overline k_0(\varepsilon)$ we have
$$ \sum^N_{n=1} 2^{-n}(\phi_n(x_k-x_j))^2 < \varepsilon^2/2$$
and by $(1)$ the proof is complete.

---

**It is all correct?** I'm also interested in proof different from mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\epsilon >0$ choose $N$ such that $\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac 1 {2^{n}} <\epsilon $. Then $||x-y||_0^{2}=\sum 2^{-n}(\phi_n(x-y))^{2}<\epsilon ||x-y||^{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{N}2^{-n}(\phi_n(x-y))^{2}$. Use a diagonal argument to get one subsequence $\{n_k\}$ such that $\phi_n (x_{n_{k}} )$ converges for each $n$.  Replace $x$ by $x_{n_{k}}$, $y$ by $x_{n_{j}}$ and take the limit as $j,k \to \infty $.

Comment: "Use a diagonal argument to get one subsequence $\{n_k\}$ such that $\phi (x_{n_{k}} )$ converges for each $n$"
Is there a misprint? You wanted to write $\phi_n (x_{n_{k}} )$?

Anyway, were we use the fact that $X$ is separable and that $(\phi_n)$ is dense in the ball?

Comment: @Ef_Ci I have changed $\phi $ to $\phi_n$. The fact that $\{\phi_n\}$ is dense is only required to show that $||.||_0$ is  a norm. it is not required to prove existence of the subsequence.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will work on your hint!